# Plain "import" is not working with webpack and babel-loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

In my `main.js` I imported some other js files which do not have export statements.

```
//main.js
import './file1'            instead import styles from './file1.js'
import './file2'
```

```
//file1.js
import './styles.scss'
function showAlert(){
   alert("file1")
}
```

```
//file2.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import component1 from './component1.vue'

Vue.use(component1) 

function showAlert2(){
  alert("file2")
}
```

Here is the configuration for webpack I used for babel-loader

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

if I use it as below

```
import a from './file1'
alert(a)
```

It's definition gets included in output file.

> Version of babel

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
```

Now if I try to call(/use it some other way) showAlert, it's not included in output files. Problem occurs only with  in production build. When I set webpack config `mode:development` it's working fine with webpack-dev-server.

Comment: Are you expecting those functions to be global? Right now they are module-scoped and not exported, so there is no way for them to ever run, so your production build doesn't bother including them.

Comment: I expect it's definition present in output file. But right now it's not the case. Perhaps babel removed it because I imported, but did not used. (Note :I also edited question.)

Comment: Webpack is an optimizing bundler. If the function is never called, there is no reason for Webpack to include the function in the final bundle. You said `Now if I try to call showAlert` how would that work? If you try to use it, it would be included in the bundle.

Comment: You are right, webpack is working as you said. `there is no reason for Webpack to include the function` in developement mode it includes all , even unused. Is there any options for webpack or plugin that help me also bundle this kind of import, or I have a workaround trick, that works. Thanks

Comment: You need to describe what "works" means in this context. If the function is never called, why does the function need to be included in the output? What is the actual code that you want to run that fails to run because of this behavior?

Comment: Actual code I want to run is , say `./file1` in above example has just import statment for style_file.scss and `./file2` has import statements for Vue components. file1 and file2 imported in main file (`import './file1'` ==> instead `import something from './file1')` **What I expect is** styles in style_file.scss should handled by sass loader. **What works is :** `import styles from './file2'  alert(style);` <= This will cause webpack to pack what is imported in file1. (Note file1 has .js extension )

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't think this is clear. If `showAlert` is never called, why is including it in the bundled code important?